# Switching Measure in a line chart with the Slicer selection on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a line chart that shows YTD revenue for the last 3 years and a line for Goal.

I have 3 slicers Region, District, and Branch all coming from the table DIMBRANCH

I have the following goals tables:

goalbyRegion

goalbyBranch

goalbyCompany

**Requirement** When nothing on the slicer is selected then the goal from table goalbycompany should be displayed.
when a region is selected, show goal on the line chart of the selected region coming in from goalbyregion table.

**Problem** Currently the revenue changes over slicer selection because the revenue is coming from a single table tbl_revenue.

[image]

The image shows the revenue and goal line charts if nothing is selected on the slicer.

DAX currently used:

```
2017/Revenue = 
VAR _year =
    YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 2
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Revenue[Revenue] ),
        FILTER ( Revenue,Revenue[Year] = _year )
    )


2018/Revenue = 
VAR _year =
    YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Revenue[Revenue] ),
        FILTER ( Revenue,Revenue[Year] = _year )
    )



2019/Revenue = 
VAR _year =
    YEAR ( TODAY () ) 
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Revenue[Revenue] ),
        FILTER ( Revenue,Revenue[Year] = _year )
    )


2019/Goals Amount = 
VAR _year =
    YEAR ( TODAY () ) 
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( GoalByCompany[GoalAmount] ),
        FILTER ( GoalByCompany, GoalByCompany[Year] = _year )
    )
```

DAX I am trying to use to achive my goal with switch function.

```
Switch Goal = 
var _region = SELECTEDVALUE(Branch[Region])
var _branch = SELECTEDVALUE(Branch[Branch])
var _district = SELECTEDVALUE(Branch[District])

var _year = year(TODAY())
var _goalregion = CALCULATE(
                    SUM(GoalByRegion[GoalAmount]),
                    FILTER(GoalByRegion , GoalByRegion[year] = _year))

var _regionselection = 
    SWITCH(_region,
        "RegionGoal",_goalregion
    )

return 
switch (_regionselection,"Region",_goalregion,blank())
```

I am not used to the switch function yet. I thought I could use this to get to my requirement.

[image]

this is when I select a region.

Here is the relationships between my tables

Additonal tables: revenue table links to branch table with branchID
calendarweek table links to date table via weekendingdate column.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your current DAX measure, and relationships between tables

Comment: @Olly Updated my question with more details as you asked Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: An alternative approach would be if you add three charts with different axis and save three different views as bookmark. With a button you could switch between the three different bookmarked views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `SWITCH`, if you're only considering whether Region is filtered or not. You can simply use an `IF` statement, to decide which measure to calculate:

```
2019/Goals Amount = 
VAR _year = 
    YEAR ( TODAY() )

RETURN
    IF ( 
        HASONEFILTER ( Branch[Region] ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( GoalByRegion[GoalAmount] ),
            FILTER ( GoalByRegion, GoalByRegion[Year] = _year )
        ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( GoalByCompany[GoalAmount] ),
            FILTER ( GoalByCompany, GoalByCompany[Year] = _year )
        )
    )
```

Comment: I tried your measure but when I selected a region "North" the revenue lines changed as per north region but the goal line remained as it is i.e. company goal.
I have three slicers region, district and branch, I need the goal line to change as per the selection made on slicer. By default no selection on slicers. i.e. ALL.

Comment: Olly, Can you please let me know if i can use hasonefilter with all of my 3 slicers for the same thing or is it just possible for 1 slicer ?

Comment: You can use multiple `HASONEFILTER`s. What are your three slicers? You mention that Region and Branch may be sliced, and that company should be the default in case of no selection. What's the third slicer? To string multiple conditions together you can do `SWITCH ( TRUE (), HASONEFILTER ( 'Branch'[Branch] ), <logic for branch>, HASONEFILTER ( 'Region'[RegionNiceName] ), <logic for region>, <logic for company> )`. The final argument to `SWITCH` is an optional ELSE condition.

Comment: @greggyb Thank you so much for your input, I used your syntax and now my problem is solved. Regarding slicers I have branch, district and region slicer but only need to work with branch and region slicer. Have a great day.